# Blazor c# change text of button to saving... then back to save

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to change the text of my save button to `Saving...` when it's clicked and then back to `Save` after the save completes. The following is what I've tried but doesn't seem to be working.

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="SaveTheCache">@saveText</button>    
</div>


@code {
    private bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    private string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    string saveText = "Save";

    private void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }

    private async Task SaveTheCache()
    {
        saveText = "Saving...";
        await _service.SaveAllTheCache();
        saveText = "Save";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `Yield` or `Delay` to allow the screen to update.

```cs
private async Task SaveTheCache()
{
    saveText = "Saving...";
    await Task.Yield();
    await _service.SaveAllTheCache();
    saveText = "Save";
}
```

You may want to consider adding logic in a similar way to disable the button and re-enable it by using a `bool` variable.

```
<div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" 
            @onclick="SaveTheCache" 
            disabled=@isSaving>
        @Label
    </button>
</div>


@code {

    bool isSaving = false;
    string Label => isSaving ? "Saving..." : "Save";

    private async Task SaveTheCache()
    {
        isSaving = true;
        await Task.Yield();
        await _service.SaveAllTheCache();
        isSaving = false;
    }
}
```