# How do I show a loading screen/icon while loading a view that requires querying a database? Asp.Net Core C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, blazor

Currently I have a view that has just a single form with three values. When a user submits the form with those three values, my controller checks if all three values actually have a value other than being empty, and if they do then it calls my service that fetches data.

```
        public IActionResult Index(string clientName = "", string tableName = "", string date = "")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(date))
            {
                // Unimportant stuff for setting temp variables for FetchData parameters removed
                TheData = _fieldDataService.FetchData(tempAcr, tempID, tableName, date, numRows);
            }
            return View(TheData);
        }
```

My goal is to make the view display a loading icon or something while the data is being fetched. I've looked into JQuery and Ajax but I have no experience with either and cannot figure out how to apply them to my specific task. Since I am using Asp.Net Core, I also looked into using Blazor, but I couldn't wrap my head around it either.

Could somebody point me in the right direction as to what I should/could use to solve this problem? I have a vague understanding that there needs to be some sort of asynchronous function that retrieves the data, but nothing more than that.

Comment: Use a state variable that you change when the query is in progress. There is no need to use JQuery/ajax. This type of state update change has been answered many times before. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74202349/1492496

Answer (score 1):

You need to fetch the data with JavaScript and manipulate the UI to show a loader. But anyway, a request like this should be so fast, that you don't even need a loader.

I'm also a bit worried that you are passing a `tableName` as input parameter. You aren't just string concatenating the query right? You might be susceptible to SQL injections, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection.

To do a request with JavaScript, look into the XMLHttpRequest, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest, or the new way of doing it with `fetch(...)`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch.

This answer shows a more practical example: [Display loading image while ajax fetches file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646805/display-loading-image-while-ajax-fetches-file-content).

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest?`  What is it? Never heard of it... Or pehaps have forgotten of its existence

Comment: You can use that to send a HTTP request with JavaScript, to fetch the data.